# Disable -Werror via pragma clang diagnostic

Tags: clang, pragma, llvm-clang

Using `-Werror` to treat all warning as errors, I don't want to suppress a deprecated declaration warning :

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignore "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:completeName];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found it, just use warning instead of ignore :

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:completeName];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Now, I still use this deprecated API, compilation passes with `-Werror` and warning is still present (remove this API use is kept in mind).

Comment: Good one! This even works when "Treat warnings as errors" is set. It will just generate warnings, and those aren't treated as errors.